# cakephp 3.0 hidden filed bootstrap issue

Tags: php, cakephp

Hew I wrote common bootstrap css for form fields.But is applying to hidden fields also.How do I restrict for hidden fields in cakephp 3.x bootstrap.

```
 $myTemplates = [
        //'nestingLabel' => '<label{{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>{{input}}{{hidden}}',
        'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group order-status">{{content}}</div>',
        'checkboxContainer' => '<div class="checkbox">{{content}}</div>',
        'label' => '<label class="col-sm-2">{{text}}</label>',
        'input' => '<div class="col-md-3"><input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" class="form-control" {{attrs}}  /></div>',
        'select' => '<div class="col-md-3"><select name="{{name}}"{{attrs}} class="form-control">{{content}}</select></div>',           
        'textarea'=> '<div class="col-md-8"><textarea name="{{name}}" {{attrs}} class="form-control"></textarea></div>',        
    ];
$this->Form->templates($myTemplates);?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('{0} Promotion', $edit ? 'Edit' : 'Add'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        if($edit) {
            echo $this->Form->hidden('id');
            echo $this->Form->input('active', array('type' => 'checkbox','div'=>false));
        } else {
            echo $this->Form->input('active', array('type' => 'checkbox','checked' => true));
        }
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
        if($edit) {
            echo $this->Form->input('promotion_type', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => Configure::read('Sidecart.ModelOptions.Promotion.promotion_types'), 'empty' => '-- Select One --', 'disabled' => true));
            echo $this->Form->hidden('promotion_type');
        } else {
            echo $this->Form->input('promotion_type', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => Configure::read('Sidecart.ModelOptions.Promotion.promotion_types'), 'empty' => '-- Select One --'));
        }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3.0, you can do this with [Widgets](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#adding-custom-widgets).

Create `src\View\Widget\HiddenWidget.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App\View\Widget;

use Cake\View\Widget\BasicWidget;
use Cake\View\Form\ContextInterface;
use Cake\View\Widget\WidgetInterface;

class HiddenWidget extends BasicWidget implements WidgetInterface {

  public function render(array $data, ContextInterface $context) {
    $data += [
      'name' => '',
    ];
    return $this->_templates->format('hidden' /* <-- Define the template name */, [
      'name' => $data['name'],
      'attrs' => $this->_templates->formatAttributes($data, ['name'])
    ]);
  }

}
```

Then in a view file:

```
<?php
$templates = [ // Define your templates
  'hidden' => '<input type="hidden" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}/>',
  'input'  => '<div class="col-md-3">' .
              '<input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" class="form-control" {{attrs}}/>' .
              '</div>'
];

$this->Form->templates($templates); // Update the templates in FormHelper
$this->Form->addWidget('hidden', ['Hidden']); // Add the HiddenWidget to FormHelper

echo $this->Form->hidden('id'); // Renders with the 'hidden' template
echo $this->Form->input('name'); // Renders with the 'input' template
```

Conversely, you may want to do the opposite and create `BsFormControlWidget`(s) instead. This way, the input fields (hidden and visible) keep their "out-of-the-box" functionality. Your custom implementation would sit alongside -Cake, in general, seems to prefer being built "on-top-of" rather than morphed. Plus your widgets would now be more easily reusable in other projects.